# How to list users by custom field?

Tags: wordpress, profile

I have a custom user field in the standard database, called "company".
I want to output on to a page the usermeta info only of users whose "company" matches "Widgets Inc" ...

How do I do that?

What I think I'd like to be able to do is avoid putting this in a page template and instead create a shortcode to list user info, with functionality to limit by field attribute - ie. {listusers company="Widgets Inc"}

But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
add_shortcode( 'list-company-users', 'company_users_shortcode' );
function company_users_shortcode($atts)
{
    ob_start();
    $query = array('meta_key' => 'company', 'meta_value' => 'Widgets Inc');

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($query);

// User Loop
    if (!empty($user_query->results)) {
        foreach ($user_query->results as $user) {
            echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No users found.';
    }
    $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
}
```

And here is your short code `[list-company-users]`

To define to use parameters in short code you can do like this

```
[list-company-users company="Widgets Inc"]
```

Now you have to extract the values passed in shortcode via `shortcode_atts()`

```
 extract(shortcode_atts(array("company" => 0), $atts));


function company_users_shortcode($atts)
{
    ob_start();
    extract(shortcode_atts(array("company" => 0), $atts));
    $query = array('meta_key' => 'company', 'meta_value' => $atts[company]);

    $user_query = new WP_User_Query($query);

// User Loop
    if (!empty($user_query->results)) {
        foreach ($user_query->results as $user) {
            echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No users found.';
    }
    $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
    return $myvariable;
}
```

### References

[**Create a Shortcode**](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/create-a-shortcode-to-list-posts-with-multiple-parameters/)

[**WP_User_Query**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query)

Comment: thanks so much - but how do I call the attribute change? I see that "Widgets Inc" is the default "company" - but how do I do, say, [list-company-users company="Sprockets Corp"] instead? I will want to list users from multiple companies on a single page. Thanks!

Comment: This works, dianuj, thanks. One thing, however; it won't display users whose "company" contains an ampersand (&). How can I route around that?

Comment: @RobertAndrews try to decode the characters like `'meta_value' => urldecode($atts[company]);`

Comment: dianuj: `urldecode` works on that part - but only if I use `"%26"` on the Page side, ie. `[list-company-users company="Widgets %26 Sprockets Inc"]`. So where do I urldecode the parameter as it hits the code, so that users can write characters like ampersands without having to convert them themselves?

Comment: @RobertAndrews i already told you put urldecode here **'meta_value' => urldecode($atts[company]);** in your code, isn't it make sense ?

Comment: That is in. See... ` add_shortcode( 'list-company-users', 'company_users_shortcode' );
 function company_users_shortcode($atts)
 {
  ob_start();
  extract(shortcode_atts(array("company" => 0), $atts));
  $query = array('meta_key' => 'company', 'meta_value' => urldecode($atts[company]));
 
  $user_query = new WP_User_Query($query);
 
 // User Loop
  if (!empty($user_query->results)) {
   foreach ($user_query->results as $user) {
    echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
   }
  } else {
   echo 'No users found.';
  }
  $myvariable = ob_get_clean();
  return $myvariable;
 }
`